# How to bypass a validation rule for Automated Process user in tests

Tags: apex, unit-test, validation-rule, platform-event, automated-process

I'm trying to bypass a validation rule on Account Object for a test.

It's ok when I create the accounts, I assigned a mocked permission set to the user creating the Accounts with a custom permission 'Bypass_VR' and added `NOT($Permission.Bypass_VR) &&`  at the beginning of my rule.

But I'm trying to test an updated performed by a trigger on a platform event, so that update is run as Automated Process.

Since my test class is annotated with `SeeAllData=false` it seems to be a test generated automated user (yet I'm not sure about that) : its Name is something like '*autoproc@00d...............*' as showed me a debug : `System.debug('checkUser ' +  UserInfo.getUserId() + ' '  + UserInfo.getUserName());`

However a query in my test class like `[SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE  name like '%autoproc%']` returns nothing so I can't assign the permission set to this user.

Even if I usually prefer not adding test exceptions in my code I have tried to assign the permission set from the trigger handler class itself with a statement like :

```
    if (Test.isRunningTest()){
        TestClass.insertPSA(new Set<Id>{UserInfo.getUserId()});
    }
```

and a method like

```
public static void insertPSA(Set<Id> userIds){
    String name = EncodingUtil.base64Encode( Blob.valueOf(
     Datetime.now().format('EmsS')+String.valueOf(Crypto.getRandomInteger())
    )).replaceAll('[^A-Za-z]', '').substring(0,12) ;
    PermissionSet ps = new PermissionSet();
    ps.Name = name;
    ps.Label = name;
    insert ps;
    SetupEntityAccess sea = new SetupEntityAccess();
    sea.ParentId = ps.Id;
    sea.SetupEntityId = [select Id from CustomPermission where DeveloperName = 'Bypass_VR'][0].Id;
    insert sea;
    PermissionSetAssignment[] psas = new List<PermissionSetAssignment>();
    PermissionSetAssignment psa;
    for (Id userId : userIds){
         psa = new PermissionSetAssignment();
         psa.AssigneeId = userId;
         psa.PermissionSetId = ps.Id;
    }
    insert psas;
}
```

The permission set is assigned but has no effect...

Thanks for reading, and for helping  ;)

Comment: you could use the metadata type `PlatformEventSubscriberConfig` and assign the running user to be different than the default Automated Process user. This has other benefits as well. You do this outside of the testmethod. In my org, I have a "service" user seat assigned to my PEs under username `myorg_automated_process`. That service user could be assigned the permission set